# When to use the autorelease pool

Tags: ios, objective-c, autorelease

I need to push a view controller if the network is reachable. After the view controller is done, I want the memory to be released. The code I have is

```
Reachability* reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
BOOL isReachable = [reachability isReachable];
if(isReachable) {
    ViewController *ppc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ppc animated:YES];
}
```

To pop the view controller, I use the following code inside (ViewController.m)

```
-(void) goBack {
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

When I see the memory usage in instruments, I don't see any memory being released when view controller is  popped. So I modified the code as below.

```
@autoreleasepool {
    Reachability* reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    BOOL isReachable = [reachability isReachable];
    if(isReachable) {
        ViewController *ppc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:ppc animated:YES];
    }
}
```

When I run above code, there is a memory drop the moment VC is pushed. But I expect the memory to drop when VC is popped. What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: You don't need the autoreleasepool. If the memory isn't being released when you pop the view controller then you probably have a reference cycle holding onto the view controller.

Comment: The use of the `autorelease` method in your code indicates that you aren't using ARC.

Comment: @rmaddy There's a difference between the `@autoreleasepool` directive and the `autorelease` **method**. OP is using the `autorelease` **method**, which is prohibited when using ARC.

Comment: @user3386109 My bad. I was looking at the `@autoreleasepool` line and totally overlooked the call to `autorelease` and as a result I misread your comment. You are correct, this is MRC code, not ARC.

Comment: My bad. The auto release in the view controller init was not intended. I am using ARC. So auoreleasepool is not needed ?